# How to display current date in repeating context with XSL 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, repeat

I am trying to display the current date, inside a repeating context, where my element is outside the repeating context.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <AllLines>
        <Versions>
            <field1>V1.0</field1>
            <field2>A1.0</field2>
        </Versions>
        <Versions>
            <field1>V2.0</field1>
            <field2>A2.0</field2>
        </Versions>
        <Versions>
            <field1>V3.0</field1>
            <field2>A3.0</field2>
        </Versions>
        <Versions>
            <field1>V4.0</field1>
            <field2>A4.0</field2>
        </Versions>
        <Versions>
            <field1>V5.0</field1>
            <field2>A5.0</field2>
        </Versions>
    </AllLines>
    <CurrentLines>
        <CurrentLine date="21 Aug">
            <field1>X1.0</field1>
            <field2>Y1.0</field2>
            <field3>Y1.0</field3>
        </CurrentLine>
        <CurrentLine date="30 Jan">
            <field1>X2.0</field1>
            <field2>Y2.0</field2>
            <field3>Y2.0</field3>
        </CurrentLine>
        <CurrentLine date="02 Feb">
            <field1>X3.0</field1>
            <field2>Y3.0</field2>
            <field3>Y3.0</field3>
        </CurrentLine>
        <CurrentLine date="21 Aug">
            <field1>X4.0</field1>
            <field2>Y4.0</field2>
            <field3>Y4.0</field3>
        </CurrentLine>
        <CurrentLine date="03 Jan">
            <field1>X5.0</field1>
            <field2>Y5.0</field2>
            <field3>Y5.0</field3>
        </CurrentLine>
    </CurrentLines>
</root>
```

My sample template will look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="displayDate">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/AllLines/Versions">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="field1" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="field2" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block border-bottom="1pt solid black" margin-bottom="4pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="/root/CurrentLines/CurrentLine[current()]/@date" />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

With the above template, I am generating the following output:

```
V1.0
A1.0
21 Aug
--------
V2.0
A2.0
21 Aug
-------
V3.0
A3.0
21 Aug
------
V4.0
A4.0
21 Aug
------
V5.0
A5.0
21 Aug
```

The third element in each repeating group, is always going to display the first date attribute, from `/root/CurrentLines/CurrentLine`.

The expected result will be:

```
V1.0
A1.0
21 Aug
--------
V2.0
A2.0
30 Jan
-------
V3.0
A3.0
02 Feb
------
V4.0
A4.0
21 Aug
------
V5.0
A5.0
03 Jan
```

Is there any way I can still keep repeating after `Versions` and display the current fields, but have the current `@date` attribute displayed based on the corresponding current `CurrentLine` element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/AllLines/Versions">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="field1" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="field2" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block border-bottom="1pt solid black" margin-bottom="4pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/CurrentLines/CurrentLine[$i]/@date" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```